# spock not finding unit tests

Tags: groovy, spock

Groovy newbie still trying to learn the ecosystem.  Today's attempt is Spock, since that seems to be how all the cool kids are writing tests now.

I hacked together the first example from the [Spock Example Project](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example)...my only change is that I'm trying to use Grape for dependency management, rather then Gradle/Maven/Ant because I still don't know those things

```
@Grab(group='org.spockframework', module='spock-core', version='2.1-groovy-2.5')
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyFirstSpecification extends Specification {
    def "length of Spock's and his friends' names"() {
        expect:
        name.size() == length

        where:
        name     | length
        "Spock"  | 5
        "Kirk"   | 4
        "Scotty" | 6
  }
}
```

When I run this with `groovy Spock1.groovy`, I get a very long stack trace, which begins with

```
$ groovy Spock1.groovy 
May 07, 2022 8:12:29 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.EngineDiscoveryRequest.getDiscoveryListener()Lorg/junit/platform/engine/EngineDiscoveryListener;
```

I've also tried annotating the test method with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` (hey, it seemed to work with the vanilla JUnit5...), and that throws a different error.

Comment: What version of groovy are you running? The version of Spock you are retrieving is for groovy 2.5, which is rather out of date by now. I'm just curious if there might be a version mismatch here.

Comment: BTW, your test worked for me in groovyConsole when I used `version='2.1-groovy-3.0'`. This is clearly not a solution, but it might be a useful extra datapoint in your search for a solution.

Comment: How are you trying to run the tests? I would honestly suggest to just use either gradle or maven from the example project and work with that. Or, if you just want to experiment, just use the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?gist=58f61cf36e112ff654041eeec8d11a98) it can runs Spock directly